# Downstream O2 sensor shows lean but LTFT is negative

Tags: exhaust, cel, fuel-injection, catalytic-converter

I have a 2011 Chevy Traverse with a P2099 CEL that I can't get to go away. I used an OBD scanner to watch the live O2 and fuel trim data. The downstream O2 sensor on bank 2 (side that P2099 refers to) will register around 0.1 volts for a while, jump up to 0.6 volts for a while, and go back and forth. (NOT rapid fluctuation like the upstream O2 sensors register).

The long term fuel trim on this bank was -7% on this test drive. The saved info with the code showed the LTFT at -9.4%.

From my understanding a low voltage of 0.1v means it is lean. I also understand that a negative fuel trim value means the engine is trying to lean the fuel mixture. I also read that the computer looks at the downstream O2 sensor data to determine LTFT.

So I am confused. If my O2 sensor is registering lean, why is the computer trying to further lean the fuel mixture? Perhaps my underlying assumptions are incorrect, if so clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked your exhaust for leaks? A leak will introduce air into the exhaust system making the downstream O2 sensor appear more lean than it should be.

Comment: Are you seeing similar fluctuations on the post cat sensor as well?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Yes my mechanic already looked for leaks, he said they found a tiny one on the joint right after the CAT and before the downstream O2 sensor. He fixed it. Still getting code and weird readings.

Comment: @GdD The slowly fluctuating sensor I referred to is the post cat sensor bank 2. The post cat sensor on bank one (no code on that side) stays consistently around 0.6v which is what I would expect.

Comment: Is Bank 1 Sensor 1  switching back and forth, ie  200-800 millivolts?

Comment: @BillSullivan bank 1 is fine, bank 2 is throwing the code. B1S1 rapidly goes up and down between 0.1-0.9v. B1S2 is consistent at ~0.6v. B2S1 goes up and down between 0.1-0.9v, but interestingly it fluctuates less than B1S1, it's a little lazier I guess you could say. B2S2 is the one that will periodically drop down to 0.1v from the 0.6v.

Comment: I would try adding propane to the air intake while monitoring my bank 1 and bank 2 upstream oxygen sensors. You should be able to drive both sensors full rich. If this test is good, add propane around all areas of intake manifold while monitoring short term fuel trims both banks and see if you can catch a change in stft's while doing this. A cracked or split vacuum hose can cause these sort of problems.

Comment: @BillSullivan thanks for the suggestions

Comment: I think you can use an engine start spray for that test @BillSullivan?

Comment: @GdD yes you can, but my preference is propane or carb cleaner. Thank You.

Comment: @Mr. Spock-have you done a smoke test on the intake and exhaust?

Comment: @BillSullivan I took it to a mechanic previously after the code first appeared and he said he found a tiny leak at the tail end of the cat where it joins the downstream exhaust pipe, just before the downstream O2 sensor. He fixed it, but then the code came back. I am not sure exactly what kind of test he did to find that leak.